# Bootstrap 4 nav bar active issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm using `Laravel 5.5` and I want to build a single layout but I can't do what I want to do.
So this is the problem I used `Bootstrap 4` and copy a sample nav bar like this (code below)

```
<nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" style="padding-left: 75px; margin-top: -16px;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="{{url('/')}}">News</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('/laptops')}}">Sports</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('/pc')}}">Science</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
```

The thing is the active status won't switch when i change my directory is there some way this would work.

PS: I see other problem like this but the `href` tag is locating an `ID` property not a `link` directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well what you are doing here is setting the active class to just one element of your navbar. what you need is something that will dynamically change the active class when the respective link is accessed. A simple example for this would be

```
<li <?=activeClass("index")?>>
    <a class = "nav-link" href="{{url('/')}}">News</a>
</li>
<li <?=activeClass("laptop")?>>
    <a class = "nav-link" href="{{url('/laptops')}}">Sports</a>
</li>
<li <?=activeClass("pc")?>>
    <a class = "nav-link" href="{{url('/pc')}}">Science</a>
</li>
```

and the php function

```
<?php 

function activeClass($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri){
        echo 'class="nav-item active"';
    }
    else{
        echo 'class ="nav-item"';
    }
}
?>
```

so basically what I did here is I set the class dynamically by comparing the passed in request uri and if it matches the current page being rendered output active class else the obvious nav-link class.The filenames above should be replaced with your own php filenames.

Comment: i got this error message ---- Exception message: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting end of file

Comment: I have edited my code forgot to put that curly in if .check it out

Comment: you missed another one for the function end curly but 'active' class still not working

Comment: it only reads this code --- else{
        echo 'class="nav-link text-light"';
    }

Comment: try an echo for $current_file_name and see weather you are getting the respective php filename or not

Comment: this what it echo's ---- href="http://localhost/cnb/public/laptops">laptops

Comment: oh that's where the problem was. we are passing the request uri parameter with php extension while we got rid of the extension in our php scrip in this line basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");. And i cross checked bootstrap docs they are setting the active class in "li" rather than "a" so i edited my code once again. If you are using your custom class n "li" replace the "nav-link" class with your own.I guess this should do the trick with no error. write me back if you get any